# In VHDL, what does an unconstrained array's index range default to when passed as an argument to a function/procedure?

Tags: vhdl

I'm using a function which returns a user-defined unconstrained array:

```
type t_array is array(integer range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

This array is then passed to a procedure. Nowhere in my procedure or function have I explicitly defined the range of the array.

What would the array's index range default to when it's passed as an argument?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.7 Procedure call statement "Execution of a procedure call includes evaluation of the actual parameter expressions specified in the call and evaluation of the default expressions associated with formal parameters of the procedure that do not have actual parameters associated with them. ... (If the formal parameter is of an unconstrained or partially constrained composite type, then any undefined index ranges of subelements of the formal parameter are determined as described in 5.3.2.2.) ". (5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges)

Comment: Note that function and procedure while both subprograms are not synonymous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will default to whatever you associate with the argument. So, in this example:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity E is
end entity ;

architecture A of E is
  type t_array is array(integer range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  procedure P (constant I : in t_array) is
  begin
    report integer'image(I'left);
    report integer'image(I'right);
  end procedure;
begin
  process
    variable V : t_array(0 to 9);
  begin
    P(V);
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture A;
```

This will be displayed:

```
# EXECUTION:: NOTE   : 0
# EXECUTION:: Time: 0 ps,  Iteration: 0,  Instance: /E,  Process: line__19.
# EXECUTION:: NOTE   : 9
# EXECUTION:: Time: 0 ps,  Iteration: 0,  Instance: /E,  Process: line__19.
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2zNy

---

Given that you don't know what the range of the input will be, rather than peppering your code with `'left` and `'right` attributes and getting in a complete pickle with `to` and `downto`, it sometimes helps to normalise the input, eg:

```
  procedure P (constant I : in t_array) is
    variable normalised_I : t_array(1 to I'length) := I;
  begin
    ...
  end procedure;
```

Comment: If `I` being passed to the procedure was indexed as `(n downto m)` would we get an error because the range of `normalized_I` uses `to`?

Comment: No. arrays of the same length can always be assigned to each other, irrespective of direction. (7 downto 0) <= (0 to 7) with map 7 <= 0, 6 <= 1 etc, so 'left and 'right values are the same. However, it is illegal to slice a vector in the wrong direction - hence why @MatthewTaylor normalised in the function. Another normalisation method is to use an alias. `alias i_alias : t_array(1 to I'length) is I;`

Comment: There is enough ambiguity in the question, the answer and it's comments I'd encourage using IEEE Std 1076-2008 (10.7 Procedure call statement, 5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges) as a reference and particularly not inaccurately answering questions presented in comments.  A slice with the wrong direction is a *null slice* (8.5 Slice names) has an index *null range* (5.2.1) defining a *null array* (5.3.2.2) a legal construct having no elements, any error derived from it is due to lack of matching elements (compatibility). Normalize is not used in this fashion in the standard.

Comment: @user1155120 for a vector declared `constant s : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"00"` doing the following `report to_string(s(0 to 3))` gives the syntax error `Error: COMP96_0284: Direction of the discrete range must be the same as that of the prefix of the slice name.`. Hence it is an error to slice an array in the wrong direction. You get the same error in runtime if the report is inside a function/procedure where the direction is not known at compile time.

Comment: 8.5 Slice name "...It is an error if the direction of the discrete range is not the same as that of the index range of the array denoted by the prefix of the slice name."  Became an error -1993 (-1987 6.5 Slice Names "...The slice is a *null slice* if the discrete range is a null range, or if the direction of the discrete range is not the same as that of the object denoted by the prefix of the slice name." The example "DATA(24 to 25)      -- a null slice", originally).